# Implementing a Remember me for Spring-Social

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-social

I have a spring security enabled project. I have implemented a remember me using the login form which works fine. But I also have on the login form social logins from google/ facebook which work fine. The problem is that they do not remember the user. Is there a way to set a similar "remember me" functionality?

My current spring config for the normal login page:

```
<http access-denied-page="/login?authorization_error=true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="formAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/account/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <remember-me key="iRemember"
            token-validity-seconds="1209600" user-service-ref="formClientDetailsUserService" />
        <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login?authentication_error=true"
            default-target-url="/account/" login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/login.do" />
        <logout logout-success-url="http://example.com" logout-url="/logout" />
        <anonymous />
    </http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched to Java config and created the remember me service:

```
@Bean
public MyRememberMeServices myRememberMeServices(){
        MyRememberMeServices service = new MyRememberMeServices (REMEMBERME_KEY, formUserDetailsService);
        service.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        service.setCookieName("xxxx");
        service.setParameter("_spring_security_remember_me");
        service.setTokenValiditySeconds(123);
        return service;
    };
```

and then on the SignInAdapter implementation for the social login:

```
@Override
public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {

    // load the user based on the account id

    // create an authentication object to store in context


    // set remember-me cookie
    myRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(
        (HttpServletRequest) request.getNativeRequest(),
        (HttpServletResponse) request.getNativeResponse(),
        authentication);

    // forward to the original URL
    return extractOriginalUrl(request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some similar requirement.

I tried to have the url for authentication as `/auth/facebook?_spring_security_remember_me=true` (refer `AbstractRememberMeServices.rememberMeRequested`). But then, [org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.detectRejection](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/security/SocialAuthenticationFilter.java#L165) wouldn't not let this pass. It is coded like this:

```
protected boolean detectRejection(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Set<?> parameterKeys = request.getParameterMap().keySet();
    return parameterKeys.size() > 0 
            && !parameterKeys.contains("oauth_token") 
            && !parameterKeys.contains("code") 
            && !parameterKeys.contains("scope");
}
```

I think if we can add another clause there, it could work. Then I thought to override it by subclassing `SocialAuthenticationFilter`. But then in `SpringSocialConfigurer` it's not injected, but instanciated using the `new` keyword. Subclassing `SpringSocialConfigurer` also doesn't seem like a solution, because there are many useful private fields inside. So, I think a solution would be to just copy `SpringSocialConfigurer` into another class, and use that along with a subclassed `SocialAuthenticationFilter`. If I have understood all this correctly, all this seems like hacking, and I think we should create a ticket for proper remember me support.

Of course, if we want remember me to be always on, that's easy by setting the `alwaysRemember` field of the `RememberMeServices`, and I am doing it this way:

```
@Bean
public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {

    TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices(rememberMeKey, userService);
    rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    return rememberMeServices;

}
```

Comment: I am interested in always having the remember me and I have added the setAlwaysRemember(true). But it seems like spring is ignoring it for social. So how do I tie the RememberMeServices to social?

Comment: rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true) just as set above was working for me, as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I did to integrate `RememberMeServices` with `Spring social`. Just like @Sanjay says, its based on `AlwaysRemember=true` logic.

Instead of default `TokenBasedRememberMeServices`, we customize a little:

```
public class DynamicRememberMeServices extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices {

public final static String PARAM_BASED_KEY = "remember-me-param-based"; 
public final static String REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "remember-me";

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public DynamicRememberMeServices(String key, UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
    super(key, userDetailsService);
    super.setParameter(REMEMBER_ME_KEY);
    super.setCookieName(REMEMBER_ME_KEY);
}

@Override
protected boolean rememberMeRequested(HttpServletRequest request, String parameter) {
    if("on".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter(PARAM_BASED_KEY)) ){
        logger.debug("param based request");
        return super.rememberMeRequested(request, parameter);
    }
    logger.debug("always remember me");
    return true;
}
```

}

and on the `login.html`:

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
   User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> 
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="remember-me-param-based" value="on" /> 
   Remember me: <input type='checkbox' name='remember-me' checked="checked"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
</form>

<a th:href="@{/auth/facebook}">Or via facebook</a>
```

So in case of facebook login(via `/auth/facebook`), it will use `AlwaysRememberMe` strategy by returning `true`, but for traditional `form-login`, it depends:

- If `remember-me-param-based=on` from the request body, it will check continue as traditional `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` based on the given Parameter(`remember-me`).
- If `remember-me-param-based` is missing, it works as `AlwaysRememberMe`.

IMHO my implementation at least gives the choice for "traditional login" users.

Comment: I tried your way but still I cannot tie the RememberMe service to the social login. Is there a setting for that?

Comment: you are using ```SocialAuthenticationFilter``` instead of ```ProviderSignInController``` right? If so, you just inject it in a regular way like ```http.rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())```.

Comment: @beku8 can you provide an example of http.rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())  while using SocialAuthenticationFilter ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, the original way it was asked (with XML config), Spring Security 3.2+ supports the services-ref attribute on the remember-me element. So in your security config you would have:

```
<security:http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  ...
  <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="secret-key">
</security:http>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="com.example.MyRememberMeServices">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="secret-key" />
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService" />
  <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```

where MyRememberMeServices can be checklist's version or beku8's DynamicRememberMeServices. I prefer beku8's version since it leaves the choice of enabling remember-me for normal logins.

Comment: combined your approach with beku8's version. didn't work